# Assign same random uuid to every row

Tags: postgresql

This obviously results:

```
SELECT *, uuid_generate_v4() FROM fruits;

apple      |f6b9a8a5-31c9-4917-9649-f366b7c12492
orange     |a55da08f-95a0-4f33-b536-866a3eae71e9
```

I know I could do

```
SELECT * FROM fruits LEFT OUTER JOIN uuid_generate_v4() ON TRUE;
```

But is there some nicer way to assign same uuid?
I'm mostly interested on conceptual level, the uuid() function is just example.

Comment: You - by the way - don't need an outer join, you can do with `fruits JOIN uuid_generate_v4() ON TRUE`. Which in turn can be simplified to `fruits CROSS JOIN uuid_generate_v4()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to make sure that `uuid_generate_v4()` is only called once.

Your solution is essentially doing that. Other solutions only vary in the syntax being used.

You could use a common table expression to somehow express that in your query:

```
with data (id) as (
   select uuid_generate_v4()
)
SELECT *
FROM fruits 
  cross join data;
```

As the CTE only returns a single row, the cross join won't increase the number of rows in the complete result. Alternatively you could use an "implicit" cross join to make it shorter:

```
with data (id) as (
   select uuid_generate_v4()
)
SELECT *
FROM fruits, data;
```

Or you could remove the CTE and use the function call in a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits, (select uuid_generate_v4() as id);
```